# R: power function fitting - error fix and more

Tags: r, error-handling, non-linear-regression

I would like to fit a power model of type:

```
y = b*x(^z)
```

My data is Animals data from mass packages.

My code is here:

```
library(MASS)
nls(brain~b*body^z,start = list(b = 0, z = 1),data=Animals)
```

It has an error I don't know how to fix

```
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

And I want to ask is this right to fit this model use my function.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If b = 0 then a small perturbation of z will have no effect on the value of the rhs so its singular as it stated.

Comment: im sorry, i am new to r, can you tell me how to set b and z. thanks

Comment: you set the starting value of b to 0. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two mistakes.  One is the singular gradient due to b=0, the other is the fact that there are two different types of animals that follow completely different distributions.

Look at the distribution:

[image]
Fixing the singular gradient still produces an error:

```
> nls(brain~b*body^z,start = list(b = 0.1, z = 1),data=Animals)
Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
  Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
```

Therefore, you should also do this:

```
subset(Animals, ! body > 9000) -> mammals
nls(brain~b*body^z,start = list(b = 0.1, z = 1),data=mammals)
Nonlinear regression model
  model: brain ~ b * body^z
   data: mammals
      b       z 
15.5540  0.6795 
 residual sum-of-squares: 4301588

Number of iterations to convergence: 13 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.321e-06
```